# DirectX 10+. Копирование текстуры в буфер

Tags: directx

Требуется использовать данные текстуры как z-координату в вертексном буфере. Как организовать копирование из текстуры в буфер, или реинтерпретировать текстуру как буфер? MSDN говорит, что при использовании метода `ID3D10Device::CopyResource` типы ресурсов должны быть одинаковыми, поэтому копирование "в лоб" не срабатывает. Сейчас вынужден тягать данные туда обратно через CPU, что совсем не комильфо с точки зрения быстродействия. 
Есть ли более эффективные решения?

Answer (score 4):

Вообще задача звучит как попытка нарисовать ландшафт, но т.к. это напрямую не указано, будем предполагать всякое.

Итак, если Вы действительно хотите использовать текстуру как хейтмэп при рисовании ландшафта, то как было указано выше, вы можете просто читать текстуру в вершинном шейдере. При этом предполагается, что сетку вы уже сформировали заранее, и текстурные координаты для каждой вершины уже вычислены. Остается лишь правильно объявить ресурсы. Если в карте высот будет лишь один численный компонент на один пиксель (т.е. один цветовой канал, например, R), то ресурс текстуры должен будет иметь формат:

```
DXGI_FORMAT_R16_FLOAT или DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT
```

И в шейдере должен быть объявлен как

```
Texture2D<float>            Texture : register(t0);
```

Тогда читать из текстуры данные в вершинном шейдере можно следующим образом:

```
float h = Texture.SampleLevel(Sampler, Tex,0);
```

Обратите внимание, что:
1. Формат ресурса имеет в конце слово _FLOAT (там есть еще форматы типа DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UNORM, которые представляют нормализованные данные, т.е изменяющиеся только в пределах 0..1). 
2. В объявлении ресурса в шейдере также есть ключевое слово , обозначающее, что ресурс имеет не нормализованные данные внутри. Это логично для карты высот, представляющей смещение вершины по вертикали в мировых координатах.
3. Для получения данных из текстуры используется функция SampleLevel - это потому, что в вершинном шейдере нельзя использовать просто Sample - система не знает, по какому критерию выбрать Mip-уровень автоматически и вы получите ошибку "error X4532: cannot map expression to vs_*_* instruction set".

Теперь, что касается того же самого чтения текстур в вершинном шейдере, но когда нам не доступны координаты текстур и мы должны их получать из текстуры данные в зависимости от порядкового номера вершины в буфере.

Вот [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb509647(v=vs.85).aspx) можно встретить описание предопределенных констант и системных ключевых слов, которые дают доступ к различным системным значениями, и нас прежде всего интересует SV_VertexID. Эта системная константа объявляется во входных данных в вершинный шейдер, также, как вы объявляете входные координаты вершины:

```
struct VS__INPUT
{
    float4 Pos          : POSITION;
    uint   VertexID     : SV_VertexID;
};
```

Это номер вершины, пришедшей на конвейер, начиная с 0. По нему мы можем легко определить, какая вершина в из буфера сейчас обрабатывается и таким образом получить необходимую координату для чтения из текстуры.

Пример использования [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/bb232912(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Чувак, ты крут!

Answer (score 1):

А запихать логику в вертексный шейдер не катит? В нем можно спокойно читать вашу текстуру и менять координаты точек.

Копирование вряд ли сработает, вы хотите странной логики, ее нужно писать вручную соосно.

Comment: Кстати, да! отличная идея, обязательно попробую. Спасибо.

Comment: Возникла проблема с сэмплингом тектуры в вертексном шейдере. Texture2D::sample не входит в набор инструкций вертексного шейдера.